# How to modify variable inside ansible jinja2 template

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I am passing a variable called `x_version=v5.5.9.1` to the Ansible jinja2 template(bash).
But inside the receiving bash script (jinja2) variable `x_version` should be modified to `v5.5.9`.

```
version_defined_in_ansible={{ x_version }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below modification helped me.

```
version_defined_in_ansible=v{{ x_version.split('v')[1][0:5] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the variable

```yaml
x_version: v5.5.9.1
```

The simplest approach is to [split the extension](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)

```yaml
{{ x_version|splitext|first }}
```

evaluates to

```yaml
v5.5.9
```